# "Creation and deletion of accounts are performed automatically" or ".. is performed automatically"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects

> Creation and deletion of Active Directory accounts **are** performed automatically during recruitment or dismissal of the employee, respectively.

I'm proofreading this text and I feel like there should be **is** there, but I can't explain why. We have a compound subject, "creation and deletion of accounts", and the parts of the compound subject are joined by **and**, so logically we should use **are**.

I'm not sure about this case. Should there be **are** or **is**?

Maybe I get this feeling because "and" here really means "or", because we have "or" in "recruitment or dismissal"?

Comment: Ask yourself: are 'creation' and 'deletion' one thing, or more than one thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you imagine the implied definite articles

> The creation and the deletion of (...) accounts

then the need for 'are', or even 'are both',  becomes a bit clearer.

But to solve the problem you describe as *"and" here really means "or"* it might be better to re-order the sentence.

> Active Directory accounts are created or deleted automatically
> during the recruitment or dismissal of an employee.

The repeated use of "or" pairs 'create' with 'recruit', and 'delete' with 'dismiss'.

Or you might use slashes:

> Active Directory accounts are created/deleted automatically
> during the recruitment/dismissal of an employee.

"Performed" just gets in the way!